# Why Is $\frac{163}{\operatorname{ln}(163)}$ a Near-Integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The $j$-function and the fact that 163 and 67 have class number 1 explain why:

$\operatorname{exp}(\pi\cdot \sqrt{163}) = 262537412640768743.99999999999925$,

$\operatorname{exp}(\pi\cdot \sqrt{67}) = 147197952743.9999987$.

But is there any explanation for these?:

$\frac{163}{\operatorname{ln}(163)} = 31.9999987 \approx 2^5$,

$\frac{67}{\operatorname{ln}(67)} = 15.93 \approx 2^4$,

$\frac{17}{\operatorname{ln}(17)} = 6.00025$.

These numbers seem too close to integers to occur by chance.

Comment: Besides the excellent question, what are other almost integers that have an "explanation" except $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ and similar numbers?

Comment: "These numbers seem too close to integers to occur by chance" Why that? The set of near-integers is simply to big to have a reasonable explanation for every single element.

If 15.9 is a near-integer for you, then it seems that ~20% of all real numbers (i.e. all elements of $[0,1/10) \cup (9/10,1]$ and all its translates) are near-integers. That's way to much to "explain" anything. Most of these numbers are near-integers because of pure probability.

Comment: All the numbers n (n/ln(n)) are prime...

Comment: @ Gjergji Zaimi: good question I guess the 'explanation' that tells us why exp(pi*sqrt(163)) is a near-integer helps us to explain why 163/ln(163) is a near-integer as well... both operations on 163 have to do with $e$.

Comment: Let me believe that this is still related to the modular invariant. One applies a different asymptotics for two sides of the equality $j(\tau)=j(-1/\tau)$, where $\tau=\sqrt{-163}/2$. For the lhs one uses $j(\tau)=1/q+744+O(q)$ where $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$, while for the rhs... What could be used for estimating $j(\tau')$ if $\operatorname{Im}(\tau')$ is small?

Comment: Max, a very nice explanation of the almost integrality of $e^{\pi\sqrt{-D}}$ can be found in Zagier's lectures "Elliptic modular forms and their applications", Chapter 6 (published recently by Springer in "1-2-3 modular forms"). He also explains a high factorisation properties of the corresponding integers (they are cubes!).

Comment: $\| n / log(n) \|$ (distance to the nearest integer) hits a new record low for $n=$ 2, 5, 9, 13, 17, 163, 53453, 110673, 715533, .... 

Comment: @Gjergji: The fine structure constant is suspiciously close (as has often been observed) to the reciprocal of 137.

Comment: Being near an integer it is also of course near a rational... which gets me thinking about continued fractions.  I wonder what the continued fraction expansion of these 'near integer' examples look like.

Comment: Here's a question: is this an exceptional number of record lows?  I'd also argue that the fact that 53453/163 is exceptionally large (naively one would expect each record low to be something like $e$ times the previous one) is connected to the fact that 163/log(163) is exceptionally near an integer.  (If we picked real numbers at random, only one out of every 400,000 is as close to an integer as 163/log(163).)  Compare, say, 355/113 as an approximation of $\pi$.

Comment: For a quick reference on the "original" examples,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number 

Not news, just convenient. Also, one can use the MO search feature with 163, there were earlier questions that had substantial answers.

Comment: $\exp(\pi\sqrt{17}) \approx 422150.9914$...

Comment: It's worth noting that the numbers 53453, 110673, 715533 do not give rise to imaginary quadratic fields with low class groups, so if anyone thought (like me) that the answer might lie in something similar, it seems it might not.

Comment: Exp(Pi*Sqrt(67))-163/ln(163) is very close to an integer if the numbers supplied in the question are correct as the first seven digits in the decimal representation are the same so when they are subtracted the difference is very close to an integer.

Comment: @Kristal, this is because both terms, the exponential and the 163 ratio, are close to integers.

Comment: They are closer to each other than they are to the nearest integer at least by a factor of 10 perhaps more I can't really tell since the
expansion stops before they differ.

Comment: The sequence $2, 5, 9, 13, 17, 163, 53453, 110673, 715533,\dots$ has been entered into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, with links back to MathOverflow, as https://oeis.org/A178805 – also, the related sequence https://oeis.org/A178806

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the other hand, *Mathematica* gives LogIntegral[163]=43.075210908806756346563...  and LogIntegral[67]=22.6520420103880266691324...  so this does not appear to be connected to x/Ln[x] in the context of the Prime Number Theorem

Answer (score 11):

What make us confident about some mystery in these observations?

[1st note](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/notes-4-5--continued-fractions/?firstview=1/):
"An example discovered by Srinivasa Ramanujan around 1913 is $\exp(\pi\sqrt{163})$,
which is an integer to one part in $10^{30}$, and has second continued fraction term
$1,333,462,407,511$. (This particular example can be understood from the fact
that as $d$ increases $\exp(\pi\sqrt{d})$ becomes extremely close to
$j((1 + \sqrt{-d})/2)$, which turns out to be an integer whenever there
is unique factorization of numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{-d}$ --- and $d=163$
is the largest of the 9 cases for which this is so.) Other less spectacular examples
include $e^{\pi}-\pi$ and $163/\log(163)$."

[2nd note](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507034324/http://www.mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=379102&tstart=0):
"**Any** computation involving 163 gives an answer that is close to an integer:
$$
163\pi = 512.07960\dots, \quad
163e = 443.07993\dots, \quad
163\gamma = 94.08615\dots\text{"}
$$
and
$$
\text{"}67/\log(67)=15.9345774031\dots, \quad
43/\log(43)=11.432521184\dots
$$
...nah, with class number 1 it's **not** connected.
It's just the same 163. $\ddot\smile$"

A synthetic example of my own:
$$
\root3\of{163}-\frac{49,163}{9,000}
=0.0000000157258\dots
$$
(note the double appearance of 163).

So, let's feel that the prime 163 is a supernatural number. $\ddot\smile$

**EDIT.** Another interpretation the original question is related to
the observation of Kevin O'Bryant who computed the first successive maxima
of the sequence $\|n/\log(n)\|$ where $\|\ \cdot\ \|$ denotes the distance
to the nearest integer. The existence of infinitely many terms
is guaranteed by the following

**Problem.**
For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $n$ such that $\|n/\log(n)\|<\epsilon$.

See solution by Kevin Ventullo to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28088/when-is-n-lnn-close-to-an-integer). I hope that this fact demystifies the original problem in full.